# How can I get last commit from GitHub API

Tags: git, github, github-api

Which is the best way to get the latest commit information from a git repository using GitHub API (Rest API v3).

Option 1: `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/master`
Can I assume that the object 'commit' of the response is the latest commit from branch master?

Option 2: `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits/5a2ff`
Or make two calls, one to get the sha by getting the HEAD ref from master and then get the commit information using the sha returned.

Comment: I'm using Rest API v3

Comment: Why wouldn't `/repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:branch` be the latest commit?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "last".

- for a given branch (like `master`), `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/master` is indeed the last (most recent) commit.
- But you can also consider [the last push event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent): that would represent the last and most recent commit done (on any branch), pushed by a user to this repo.

Comment: How does one use the GET idea with the api.  How is it included in the curl?

Comment: @JohnWooten See for examples https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/85bf6b02979d8a7b0308

Comment: But I need to pass an owner. How do I know that that dev was the last one pushing something to the repo?

Comment: @Dani Why passing the owner of the repository a problem in your case?

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought it was the owner of the commit. That works then

Comment: `curl --user username:mypassword "https://mygithubenterprise/api/v3/repos/myorg/myproj/commits/master"`

Comment: @SridharSarnobat True, but do not use your GHE account password, use a token: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-11-13-token-authentication-required-for-api-operations/ (nov. 2020)

Answer (score 10):

If you only need the SHA1 of the latest commit of a certain branch here's a `curl` request that will do it:

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: token {your_github_access_token}" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.sha" \ 
"https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repository_name}/commits/{branch_name}"
```

Comment: the "Accept" header is important there to just get the SHA, see https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-commit

Answer (score 10):

Another method to getting the latest commit from a user would be using the following endpoint. To clarify, this will only show `public` events so pushes to a private repository will not be shown.

```
https://api.github.com/users/<username>/events/public
```

Comment: Wow, you don't even have to authenticate. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [Github GraphQL v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to get the last commit of the default branch :

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "linux", owner: "torvalds") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 1) {
            nodes {
              message
              committedDate
              authoredDate
              oid
              author {
                email
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or for all branches :

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "material-ui", owner: "mui-org") {
    refs(first: 100, refPrefix: "refs/heads/") {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          target {
            ... on Commit {
              history(first: 1) {
                nodes {
                  message
                  committedDate
                  authoredDate
                  oid
                  author {
                    email
                    name
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository%28name%3A%20%22material-ui%22%2C%20owner%3A%20%22mui-org%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20refs%28first%3A%20100%2C%20refPrefix%3A%20%22refs%2Fheads%2F%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history%28first%3A%201%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20message%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20committedDate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20authoredDate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oid%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20author%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20email%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)