# GraphQL - How to get all the commits after a given commit?

Tags: github, graphql, commit, github-api

Is there a way in Github v4 API to get all the commits after a given commit?

I have tried this, but it doesn't give me any result.

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "karthikeayan", name: "puhar-petti") {
    ref(qualifiedName: "master") {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(last: 100, before: "d1b7ccc044be72490525a3fe1b819440f4927cba 0") {
            pageInfo {
              startCursor
              endCursor
            }
            edges {
              node {
                oid
                messageHeadline
                messageBody
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With git log I can accomplish this by doing

```
git log d1b7ccc044be72490525a3fe1b819440f4927cba..HEAD
```

Comment: i found something interesting... looks like this is not possible.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948949/get-the-metadata-for-the-first-n-commits-in-a-remote-git-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experiments, the *before* cursor is ignored.

In v4 you can search forward by pages, as in this [query.graphql](https://gist.github.com/waseem/c71fa3c8b2b2824f2cdcb34bef51dcb3#file-query-graphql) gist.

```graphql
history(first: 100, after: "d1b7ccc044be72490525a3fe1b819440f4927cba 0") {
 ...
}
```

In v3 you might be able to use the [Search Commits API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-commits) that is being previewed. However, it only searches the default branch.