# Getting the last commit date from a remote repo without cloning

Tags: git, shell, jenkins-pipeline

I want to get the last commit date in a remote repo without cloning it. Is there a way to do this ? I found several methods but for all of them to work, I need to clone the repo first and then issue the commands to get the last commit date.

Is there a way I can get the last commit date from a remote git without cloning it ?

Comment: That depends on the git server you're connecting to. Azure DevOps has a REST API you could leverage for example, GitHub as well... These APIs are platform specific though.

Answer (score 3):

If it's remote, it's on another server. This means you will need to connect to it somehow, whatever the solution. A usual solution is to just SSH:

```
ssh remote.server /bin/bash -c 'cd /path/to/remote/repo && git log --all -1 --format=%cd'
```

Some usual production UIs have rest APIs you can use etc. For Github for example, you can fetch the latest commit object with

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<user name>/<repo>/commits/<brancH>
```

(This is based on [How can I get last commit from GitHub API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726013/how-can-i-get-last-commit-from-github-api#45727280)) and parse the Json (or Yaml I don't know what they have now, Json seems enough) - under auther and commiter there are dates. If you don't know which branch has the latest commit you have to check them all.

Comment: I'll check how to do this with Github and post it here soon.

Comment: Note this only gives you the latest date of the currently checked out branch, not necessarily the latest commit on *any* branch.

Comment: @chepner oooo thanks!! Amending with `--all`.